# ReactJS - get latitude on click and show it in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

Beginner here. I have a button that gets latitude and longitude using the geolocation API. I get the location fine on my console, but I'm having trouble showing them in a input box (so that I can then post the location information later). Below is my code for the component:

```
export class GetLocation extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        latitude: '',
        longitude: ''
    };
    this.getMyLocation = this.getMyLocation.bind(this);

}

ComponentDidMount(){
    this.getMyLocation();
}
getMyLocation = (e) => {
let location = null;
let latitude = null;
let longitude = null;
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
    location = window.navigator.geolocation
}
if (location){
    location.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude= position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(latitude);
        console.log(longitude);
    })
}
    this.setState({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude})

}

render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <p>Your location is </p>
        <Field name="latitude" component="input" onChange={this.getMyLocation}/>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.getMyLocation}>Get Geolocation</button>
    </div>

    );
}
}
```

I'm using `redux-form` and this component is a part of a wizard form (in case you were wondering about the `Field` Component)

Comment: Try passing `value={this.state.latitude}` prop to your `Field` component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ComponentDidMount` should be `componentDidMount`. I believe you have to set a `value` prop to your `Field` right?

Also, as @bennygenel mentioned, you don't need to bind `getMyLocation` in the constructor since you are already using arrow function (I did on my example, feel free to change it). In order to have access to `this.state` inside `getCurrentPosition`'s callback, you either need to `bind` the success callback or make use of arrow function.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      latitude: '',
      longitude: '',
    }

    this.getMyLocation = this.getMyLocation.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMyLocation()
  }

  getMyLocation() {
    const location = window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation
    
    if (location) {
      location.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        })
      }, (error) => {
        this.setState({ latitude: 'err-latitude', longitude: 'err-longitude' })
      })
    }

  }

  render() {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state
    
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={latitude} />
        <input type="text" value={longitude} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: it works if I keep the `input` tag, but it is not working with the `Field` component. What do I have to do to make it work? The field component is connected to the entire form, so I want to make this work with this component.

Comment: I've asked a supplementary question, since I felt updating this question would completely change it. I'll mark your answer for this question as correct though. Thanks a lot. I'm going through the noob phase, so I have lots of problems.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389215/redux-form-triggerring-onchange-event-on-fireld-based-on-another-button-click/46390716#46390716

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers say you need to pass longitude and latitude values to the input so you can be able to show but there is another problem. You are not setting the longitude and latitude in the right place.

```
if (location){
    location.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude= position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(latitude);
        console.log(longitude);
        this.setState({
           latitude: latitude, 
           longitude: longitude
        }); // you should set state when you have the values.
    }.bind(this)); // you need to bind this so you can use setState
}
```

Comment: I have bound the function `getLocation` to `this`.

Comment: I've tried your solution though, but it isn't working. I see the values in console, but not visible in the input.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti you bind the `getMyLocation` function _(even though you don't need to because you are using arrow functions)_ but you didn't bind the `getCurrentPosition` callback. You need to tell `Field` component to what it should show.